# Search for strings (values) between two semicolon(s) and split in to rows

Tags: shell, unix

I have a new requirement and now I need your help and requirement as follows

The source file contains two columns (Account ID and Territory) and for one `AccountId`, `territoryId` will be stored as  `;TERR1;TERR2;TERR3;`. now I need to generate output like as below.

Source File:

```
Accoutn ID , Territory Id
--------------------------------
1      ,;TERR1;TERR1;TERR1;
```

Target Should be;[image]

```
Accoutn ID , Territory Id
--------------------------------
1         ,TERR1
1         ,TERR2
1         ,TERR3
```

I have tried with awk but couldn't succeed, Can you help me here?

Comment: Dear Sumesh, your question is a bit unclear. Could you provide us a [mcve] and please have a look at [ask]. Also, you mention you tried something, what did you try?

Comment: @kvantour , i have added screenshot of the source file  and target expected.

Comment: Please do not provide screenshots, but add actual ASCII version of the file (copy-paste). Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. And please provide the command you have tried and why they failed.

Comment: Not working vompletely, maybe an idea for someone else:
 `echo '1      ,;TERR1;TERR2;TERR3;' | sed -r ':m s/([^;]*);([^;]*);(.*)/\1\2\n\1;\3/;P; D;t m'`.

Comment: I have tried to use-  echo "ACC1,;TERR1;TERR2;TERR3;" |awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'         Its actually splitting values based on the delimeterr (;) but for me i also need to print the first column values as well - Any suggession

Comment: @WalterA , thanks for sharing the code , will try to test this let you know the results .

Answer (score 0):

In a comment I showed a `sed`-based solution, but that might be to difficult.
You can use `awk` (a good choice) or try something that will work for small files.
Learn in steps using a loop.
Read file and display lines

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "${line}"          
done < source_file
```

Echo something special when line has a ';'

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   if [[ "${line}"=~ ; ]]; then
     echo "Something special"
   else
      echo "${line}"
   fi
done < source_file
```

Do something special when line has a ';'

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
       if [[ "${line}" =~ ";" ]]; then
          while IFS= read -r field; do
             if [ -z "${firstfield}" ]; then
                firstfield="${field}"
             else
                echo "${firstfield}${field}"
             fi
           done < <( echo "${line}" | tr ';' '\n' )
       else
          echo "${line}"
       fi
    done < source_file
```

Downgrade to ksh or sh when needed
Both `if [[ .. ]]` and `<(..)` are undefined in POSIX, so you have a challenge left.